# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, stored-procedures

So I try to run this query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ImportMonetareWinmentor]
    @dataStart datetime ,
    @dataFinal datetime
AS

    set language english
        declare @erroare int

        if(@dataStart > @dataFinal) set @erroare = -1;  set language english
        declare
                  @dataStart datetime = '2011-05-15T00:47:00' ,
                  @dataFinal datetime = '2011-05-17T15:43:00'
                  print @dataStart 
                  print @dataFinal
                  EXEC [sp_ImportMonetareWinmentor] @dataStart,@dataFinal
```

My stored procedure has two datetime parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ImportMonetareWinmentor]
    @dataStart datetime ,
    @dataFinal datetime
AS
set language english
    declare @erroare int

    if(@dataStart > @dataFinal) set @erroare = -1;
            else begin  
                print('Procedure')
        return @erroare
                end
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
    END
```

Any idea why I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know it has something to do with the datetime, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong, or why does SQL want to convert my input param to date from string as they are already string.

Comment: Are you getting the error from the lines where you try to set `@dataStart` before even executing the stored procedure? And also, as a side note, you should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix - it's reserved for microsofts System Procedures.

Comment: @marc_s no, I call it from an other query... if you run the first query you would see that the dataStart and dataFinal are converted to datetime with no problem, then when I pass them to the SP i get the error.

Comment: @Damien_the_unbeliever the error it at 'AS' char from SP from what I managed to figure out.

Comment: If it isn't from the lines of indicates in my answer, then its from code that you're not showing us, since inside the stored procedure code you're showing, there's no attempt to convert or compare between strings and `datetime` values.

Comment: First selectively comment out lines and execute until you have isolated which line causes the error. My guess is you need an explicit `CONVERT` to convert those string literals to `DATETIME`

Comment: I found the problem, when I run the dynamic sql the convertion it makes from my datatime to string is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` isn't unambiguous, so far as SQL Server is concerned - it will sometimes try to interpret it as `YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm` and so trips over when it doesn't know which the 17th month is. Try:

```
declare
      @dataStart datetime = '2011-05-15T00:47:00',
      @dataFinal datetime = '2011-05-17T15:43:00'
```

---

Demonstration of the problem. This:

```
set language british
go
declare
          @dataStart datetime = '2011-05-15 00:47',
          @dataFinal datetime = '2011-05-17 15:43'
```

Generates the error. This:

```
set language english
go
declare
          @dataStart datetime = '2011-05-15 00:47',
          @dataFinal datetime = '2011-05-17 15:43'
```

doesn't.